# Can't Save response from server with Sharedpreferences

Tags: android, image, sharedpreferences

I need to use a string variable which i get from a server response.
I tried to save with Shared preferences, or just to log out, but i cant.

Its in the same activity, but i tried to show it on another activity as well.

The problem is in the saving process.

```
 String content_url="";

 public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

     try {

          Log.i("dataJson", response.toString());
              for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                 JSONObject jresponse = response.getJSONObject("dataJson");
                      String media_id = jresponse.getString("media_id");
                      String session_id = jresponse.getString("session_id");
                      String content_url = jresponse.getString("content_url");

                      Log.i("dataJson", media_id);
                      Log.i("dataJson", session_id);
                      Log.i("dataJson", content_url);

                        }

 SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("server", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
 editor.putString("content_url", content_url);
 editor.apply();


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

And for retrieving:

```
  SharedPreferences sharedPref =getSharedPreferences("server", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

  String content_url1 =sharedPref.getString("content_url", "");
  Log.i("dataJson", "Content: " + content_url1);
```

the log result: 07-29 14:55:30.362 11522-11522/? I/dataJson: Content:

I tried to put somewhere else the sharedpref part, but the result is the same.. = nothing.

what am i doing wrong?

the complett response from server:

```
 07-29 15:21:40.442 13585-13585/? I/dataJson: {"media_id":2104,"session_id":"14697845603416","content_url":"http:\/\/developlment.dev.tech.com\/upload\/2104\/content"}
```

Comment: editor.commit().. missing remove editor.apply();

Comment: Why do you use a `for` loop on a `JSONObject` ?

Comment: commit and apply are same.. but i changed, nothing new

Comment: to print out all the responses.

Comment: With your current implementation, you'll always get the last value. And you'll lose previous values.

Comment: thats okay for me. i just want the last.

Comment: @Janos Will you not need to escape the `"` in the Json responce using `\\` first?

Comment: that does not matter, i tried in another activity, and shows nothing. but yes, here I am retrieving in the onCreate method.

Comment: @MarkKeen sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: Curiously try saving your whole response (JsonObject) `response.toString` into sharedprefs and try retreiving it.

Comment: i tried that because I saw other questions about this topic, but in my case, its nothing

Answer (score 0):

> **Used**

```
 editor.commit();
```

> **Instead of**

```
 editor.apply();
```

> Note: Put Your Sharedpreference in for loop

```
   for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
             JSONObject jresponse = response.getJSONObject("dataJson");
                  String media_id = jresponse.getString("media_id");
                  String session_id = jresponse.getString("session_id");
                  String content_url = jresponse.getString("content_url");

                  Log.i("dataJson", media_id);
                  Log.i("dataJson", session_id);
                  Log.i("dataJson", content_url);


          SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("server", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

          SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
          editor.putString("content_url", content_url);
          editor.commit();

                    }
```

Comment: 07-29 15:11:20.472 12999-12999/? I/dataJson: {"media_id":2094,"session_id":"14697845603416","content_url":"http:\/\/develop.dev.tech.com\/upload\/2094\/content"}

Comment: what do you mean where is the dataJson? there is after the date and time.. 
 
07-29 15:11:20.472 12999-12999/? I/dataJson:

Comment: @Janos, you are fetching JSONObject from the response data with the key `dataJson` in the first line of your loop. Where is that object in the response?

Comment: that is just the log name to be able to filter the logs

Answer (score 0):

Change `String content_url = jresponse.getString("content_url");` to `content_url = jresponse.getString("content_url");`

You are re-declaring the same variable inside the `for` loop and so your initial variable is still blank. You need to update the initial variable with the data that you are getting.

Also, change `editor.apply();` to `editor.commit();` and log the result of `content_url` before saving in SharedPreferences.

**Edit:**

Replace you code with this. You only need to retrieve the data from the response. There's no need of `for` loop as you already know the keys in the JSONObject.

```
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
    try {
        Log.i("dataJson", response.toString());
        String media_id = response.getString("media_id");
        String session_id = response.getString("session_id");
        String content_url = response.getString("content_url");

        Log.i("dataJson", media_id);
        Log.i("dataJson", session_id);
        Log.i("dataJson", content_url);

        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("server", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putString("content_url", content_url).commit();

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: the result is same.. nothing

Comment: Yes,  I logged out, but got nothing in the log as well.

Comment: Add your complete JSON response in the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118639/discussion-between-janos-and-prerak-sola).